# Hibernate generates syntactically incorrect SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, syntax-error, criteria

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "follow_ups")
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class FollowUp extends EntityObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1343114665843716990L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dossier_id")
    private Dossier dossier;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "website_item_id")
    private WebsiteItem websiteItem;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
    private Invoice invoice;

    @Column(name = "message_date")
    @OrderBy("message_date DESC")
    private Date messageDate;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "creator")
    private BackendUser creator;

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public Dossier getDossier() {
        return dossier;
    }

    public void setDossier(Dossier dossier) {
        this.dossier = dossier;
    }

    public WebsiteItem getWebsiteItem() {
        return websiteItem;
    }

    public void setWebsiteItem(WebsiteItem websiteItem) {
        this.websiteItem = websiteItem;
    }

    public Invoice getInvoice() {
        return invoice;
    }

    public void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }

    public BackendUser getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(BackendUser creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public Date getMessageDate() {
        return messageDate;
    }

    public void setMessageDate(Date messageDate) {
        this.messageDate = messageDate;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

When using a criteria that checks anything on the invoice, invoice.id for instance, or when the invoice is fetched eagerly, the following sql is created (this is only one of many queries that it executes):

```
SELECT vatdetails0_.invoice_id  AS invoice_5_40_1_,
  vatdetails0_.id               AS id1_39_1_,
  vatdetails0_.id               AS id1_39_0_,
  vatdetails0_.invoice_id       AS invoice_5_39_0_,
  vatdetails0_.invoice_vat_type AS invoice_2_39_0_,
  vatdetails0_.vat              AS vat3_39_0_,
  vatdetails0_.vat_amount       AS vat_amou4_39_0_
FROM invoice_vat_details vatdetails0_
WHERE vatdetails0_.invoice_id IN
  (SELECT invoice11_.id
  FROM website_lots l
  WHERE l.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
  )                       = 0 THEN websiteite14_.end_date ELSE
  (SELECT MAX(l.enddate)
  FROM website_lots l
  WHERE l.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
  )
END THEN
CASE
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots wl
    INNER JOIN website_lots_auction wla
    ON wl.id               = wla.id
    WHERE wla.status       = 'AVAILABLE'
    AND wl.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id) =
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots wl
    INNER JOIN website_lots_auction wla
    ON wl.id                 = wla.id
    WHERE wl.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
    )
  THEN 5
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots wl
    INNER JOIN website_lots_auction wla
    ON wl.id               = wla.id
    WHERE wla.status       = 'AVAILABLE'
    AND wl.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id) = 0
  THEN 7
  ELSE 6
END WHEN now()              < websiteite14_.start_date THEN 2 WHEN now() >= websiteite14_.start_date THEN 1 ELSE -1
END WHEN websiteite14_.type = 'RENT' THEN 1 ELSE
CASE
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots
    INNER JOIN lots
    ON lots.id                         = website_lots.lot_id
    WHERE website_lots.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id) =
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots
    INNER JOIN lots
    ON lots.id                       = website_lots.lot_id
    WHERE lots.status                = 'SOLD'
    AND website_lots.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
    )
  THEN 3
  ELSE 1
END
END AS formula10_12_,
CASE
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots wl
    LEFT JOIN website_lots_sale wls
    ON wl.id=wls.id
    LEFT JOIN website_lots_auction wla
    ON wl.id                 =wla.id
    WHERE wl.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
    AND (wls.status         <> 'AVAILABLE'
    OR wla.status           <> 'AVAILABLE')) = 0
  THEN 'ALL'
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots wl
    LEFT JOIN website_lots_sale wls
    ON wl.id=wls.id
    LEFT JOIN website_lots_auction wla
    ON wl.id                 =wla.id
    WHERE wl.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
    AND (wls.status          = 'AVAILABLE'
    OR wla.status            = 'AVAILABLE')) = 0
  THEN 'NONE'
  ELSE 'PART'
END AS formula11_12_,
CASE
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots l
    WHERE l.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id) = 0
  THEN websiteite14_.end_date
  ELSE
    (SELECT MAX(l.enddate)
    FROM website_lots l
    WHERE l.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
    )
END AS formula12_12_,
CASE
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM website_lots l
    WHERE l.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id) = 0
  THEN NULL
  ELSE
    (SELECT MAX(l.soldDate)
    FROM website_lots l
    WHERE l.website_item_id = websiteite14_.id
    )
END                AS formula18_12_,
websiteite14_.type AS type1_80_12_
FROM follow_ups this_
INNER JOIN contacts contact2_
ON this_.contact_id=contact2_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN frontend_users frontendus3_
ON contact2_.id=frontendus3_.contact_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN backend_users backenduse4_
ON this_.creator=backenduse4_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dossiers dossier5_
ON this_.dossier_id=dossier5_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN backend_users backenduse6_
ON dossier5_.applier_backend_user_id=backenduse6_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN backend_users backenduse7_
ON dossier5_.owner_backend_user_id=backenduse7_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN commissions commission8_
ON dossier5_.id=commission8_.dossier_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN commission_brackets commission9_
ON commission8_.id=commission9_.commission_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts contact10_
ON commission8_.contact_id=contact10_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoices invoice11_
ON this_.invoice_id=invoice11_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoiceContacts invoicecon12_
ON invoice11_.id=invoicecon12_.invoice_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts contact13_
ON invoicecon12_.contact_id=contact13_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN website_items websiteite14_
ON this_.website_item_id=websiteite14_.id )
```

This query is incorrect, generated error is about the first THEN keyword which can not be used at that position, and I have never had hibernate do this before. On the internet is not that much information to find about hibernate generating a faulty query.

Criteria used is the simplest case:

```
session.createCriteria(getEntityClass())
```

What can be wrong and should I check out?
How can I dive into hibernate to see what the problem is?
Maybe it should be logged as a hibernate bug?

Used hibernate version is: 4.3.10.Final
Dialect used: POSTGRESQL.

Comment: please post your criteria..

Comment: Added it. Criteria is the simplest you can have: session.createCriteria(getEntityClass())